# how to convert no of steps in pedometer to distance in miles in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, core-motion

I am getting no of steps from core-motion
i need to get distance in miles from that step count

```
let convertedDistance = self.distance / 1609.344
let roundedDistanceinMiles = String(format: "%.2f", convertedDistance)
```

Comment: You can get the distance directly from CoreMotion, going over the Pedometer is unnecessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `distance` property from the [`CMPedometerData`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMPedometerData_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CMPedometerData) which gives you the distance in meters that way you don't need to convert the steps.

Answer (score 2):

**Find Number Of Steps Using Pedometer in iOS8 **

```
#import <CoreMotion/CoreMotion.h>
@interface HomeView : UIViewController
{
}
@property(strong,nonatomic) CMPedometer *pedometer;

in .m File
@interface HomeView ()
{
}
@end

@implementation HomeView
@synthesize  pedometer;

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
pedometer=[[CMPedometer alloc]init];
 [pedometer queryPedometerDataFromDate:midnightLastNight toDate:now1 withHandler:^(CMPedometerData *pedometerData, NSError *error)
     {
         if (pedometerData!=nil)
         {
             NSString *numberofsteps=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",pedometerData.numberOfSteps];
             totalsteps=[numberofsteps intValue];
         }



     }];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
else
    {
        float mileDistance =roundf([distance floatValue] * 0.621371);

        if (mileDistance==0)
        {
            mileDistance=0.04;
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d mi",(int)mileDistance];

        }
        else
        {
            return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d mi", (int)mileDistance];
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you convert your answer to swift , it is easy to use